# How can I compute the probability of type 1 error and power?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have got one problem as following.

> There are two coins in a box (that look very much the same). For one
>   coin, the probability of heads is $0.7$ and for the other, the
>   probability of heads is $0.1$. You will randomly select one of the
>   coins and toss it once. Based on the result of this toss, you will
>   decide which coin you have tossed. Suppose that your null
>   hypothesis is that you have selected the coin with a 70% chance of
>   heads.
>
> (1) What is the alternative hypothesis?
>
> (2) If the results of the toss is heads, will you “accept” or reject
>   the null hypothesis? Explain your reasoning.
>
> (3) What is $\alpha$ for this test?
>
> (4) What is the power for this test if the alternative hypothesis is
>   true? (Note that there is only a single possible alternative
>   hypothesis.)

I have finished the first two questions. For (1), I think the alternative hypothesis is "I have selected the coin with a $10\%$ chance of heads".

For (2), I used the the basic probability theory to compute both probabilities of getting each coins ($0.875$ v.s. $0.175$), and concluded that I will "accept" my null hypothesis.

However, I have no ideas how to approach (3) and (4). I think $\alpha$, the probability of type 1 error, should be set before the test. We can interpret it as a threshold of our test, then why and how we can compute $\alpha$?

For (4), I don't really understand why the power would depend on the alternative hypothesis? Shouldn't it be all the same? I also have no ideas how to find the power in this problem.

Any hints or suggestions would be appreciate!

Comment: I am still thinking about this problem. Can I calculate $\alpha, \beta$ using conditional probability? Like $\alpha = \mathbb{P}(reject\mid H_o)$?